# How to validate the Json property (key) name?

Tags: java, android, json

How to validate the JSON property (key) name?

I want to validate the JSON property(key) name without using schema validation,

```
@Data 
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public Student {

    private int studNo;

    @jsonProperty("studname")
    private String studname;
}
```

if I am giving the request as like

```
{
   "studNo": 50,
   "studName": "Viji"
}
```

It is accepting  the request, but i want to use below request  only

```
{       
   "studNo": 50,
   "studname": "Viji"
}
```

Please help on this.

Comment: Change `@jsonProperty("studname")` => `@jsonProperty("studName")`

Comment: @Joel I think the OP is looking for a way to force the parser to treat keys as case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jackson library then implement your code like below:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Test aaa = new Test("aaa");
        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(aaa)); //output {"a":"aaa"}
        String str = "{\"name\":\"aaa\"}"; // 
        Test test = new ObjectMapper().readValue(str, Test.class); // give exception
        System.out.println(test.getName());

    }

class Test{
    @JsonProperty(value = "a")
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Test(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```